# How many calories would a programmer (or somebody who is mostly at a desk) burn on a daily basis?

Tags: weight-loss, calories

I need to know how many calories one would burn if they just sat at a desk all the time on their 9-5.

Comment: [Not enough, so do some exercise](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6/exercises-for-a-programmer-sitting-by-the-pc-all-day/363#363)

Comment: Quite enough, actually, if they restrict what they eat. You can out-eat any amount of exercise.

Comment: @Boris If I understand you correctly as saying that totally sedentary people burn enough calories, with the corollary that exercise is irrelevant, then I wish I could downvote your comment. If I misunderstand then nevermind.

Comment: I think it's important to keep in mind the fact that [calories are not the only important aspect of a diet](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3628/1771), and that sitting at a desk all day has negative effects beyond the caloric.

Comment: Of course, I am not claiming exercise is irrelevant for health. The topic though is weight loss. Diet is way more effective for that. The problem is people trying to ignore diet.

Comment: You can lose weight without exercise, just by dieting. You may have hard time losing any weight by just doing exercise (your food intake naturally increase with exercise, if not controlled).

Comment: What is the purpose of this question? Is there a reason *why* you "need to know" how many calories you burn when sitting for 8 hours a day?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I believe Boris' point was that--within the narrow scope of weight loss--a diet would be sufficient for losing weight in this context. This is not to say that exercising provides no ancillary benefits; only that within the context and scope of this question, you do not need to exercise if you simply adhere to a diet.

Comment: @Moses I think you're right, and therefore my response is no longer entirely accurate. I still think that such an approach is reductionist and to be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

To calculate the amount of calories you burn on a daily basis you can add your **BMR** and **activity calorie expenditure**.

**Basal Metabolic Rate (BMR)** is the amount of energy your body requires at rest just to maintain your bodily functions.  The BMR is expressed in calories.  You can roughly calculate your BMR with an online [BMR calculator](http://health.discovery.com/centers/heart/basal/basal.html) using your gender, weight, height and age.

**Activity Calorie Expenditure** - Next you can use the calorie [activity calculator](http://www.healthstatus.com/calculate/cbc), entering your weight and the number of minutes "studying" to determine the additional calories you spend while sitting at your desk.

For example, a 35 y.o., 5' 7" man weighing 150#, would have a BMR of 1597 to 1611.0 calories depending on the calculator used.
Desk work for 8 hrs (or 480 minutes) adds ~ 1,008 calories for a total of 2619 calories per day (if my math is right). For metric values, here is a [metric BMR calculator](http://www.calculator.org/calculate-online/health-fitness/basal-metabolic-rate.aspx).

Realize that these calculators are approximations and do not take into account your body fat percentage.

Comment: I'd suggest the MET formula for this one, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent

Answer (score 0):

A calculator can be useful in figuring this out.  Visit this link: http://www.healthstatus.com/calculate/cbc to calculate calorie burn based on your weight.