# Want to lose weight from 90 kg to 75 kg

Tags: diet, weight-loss

I want to lose weight. Currently my weight is 90 kg.   According to my height 5'11" (1.80 m), I should be on 75 kg which I was 2 years before l came to UAE from Pakistan. I have gained weight very quickly in the span of one year and my waist reached 38. I want to go back on my previous size 34.

Today I am going to start running for weight loss, kindly advise me about diet plan which I need to follow strictly.

Comment: Related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/are-calories-the-only-important-aspect-of-a-diet/3628#3628

Comment: Might be a good idea to list what foods you're currently eating. That may help us see why you are putting on weight. Keeping a food diary for your own records will also help.

Answer (score 1):

Eat a balanced diet, avoid high fat, high sugar food. Dont go near chips (cold) or fries (hot), eat fruit between meals, and eat plenty of salad.

Have a sip of water between each mouth full of food.

Do about 30 min of exercise (quick walking or easy cycling) every day, try standing up and walk around every 10 to 15 min if you work at a desk during the day.

Loosing 500g a week is easier to achieve and keep achieving than trying to loose lots of weight quickly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid Light-products. They have sweeteners in them that influence your insulin levels and it has a negative effect on your metabolism.
2. Eat enough Protiëns (especially after sports and for breakfast).
3. Avoid Cola, Chocolate and Chips.
4. Don't sport too much, like an idiot. It leads to overeating. Sport on a normal basis.
5. Drink water or red wine. Don't drink calories (white wine, beer, light drinks, soda drinks)

These tips are from the 4-Hour Body a book by Timothy Ferriss. In the book are more tips. For me they worked well.

Comment: red win is better than white wine ????? And more comparable to water?

Comment: What is 'sport' as a verb?

Comment: point 1 is not proven yet, but you can keep it in mind. Light is better (from a diet perspective) than the 'real' stuff. Red wine contains also calories. While a glass of [red wine could be beneficial to your health](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_effects_of_wine), it adds to your calorie count. But as TS is from Pakistan / United Arabic Emirates, I don't think alcohol is on his menu.

Answer (score 0):

- Most important is your decision to reduce your weight.
- Reduce the plate size (whatever your current plate size is).
- Eat vegetables, preferably raw (the main reason for this is, it is hard for the stomach to digest it and extract valuable material from it and hence your stomach is working out for you). This will work wonder on your overall health also.
- Do some kind of physical exercise.
- To notice any change it will take time (maybe a month or so), then you can see lot of change in your weight. Initially you will lose water weight very fast but then, you have to keep doing things without losing hope. Don't give up.
- Your metabolism will increase and you will lose weight fast.
- Get a weighing machine, keep track of your progress, it is the best feeling to see your weight reduce.
- Increase your knowledge on the subject by [reading articles, blogs, others  success](http://www.exrx.net/FatLoss/WeightLossTips.html).
- It is a mind challenge than physical one.
- I am sure you will reach your target. Good luck.

Comment: Why a downvote any reason?