# What is the most effective Weightloss Drug?

Tags: weight-loss

What is the most effective weightloss medication for dietary support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not one really. The best way to lose weight is to go on a calorie deficit. [This answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/25130/30797) explains how to do a calorie deficit. It also continues to explain what your protein intake should be, which is good to know if you are weight lifting. Eat fresh produce, ie fruits and veg, so that you get your micronutrients.

Also, get active. Get on a treadmill and walk a couple/few miles. If you can, run (or work up to that point). Hit the gym and lift weights to build muscle. Muscle cells burn calories more so than fat cells.

The only supplements that I think is beneficial are protein powders and fish oil. Protein powders help one to get enough protein in (without eating stacks of meat), which is useful for bodybuilders. Fish oil has omega-3 fats and sometimes omega-6 and -9. Our bodies don't produce these so we have to consume them. However, if you're one for fish dishes then you're probably getting enough omega fats.

Finally, I have read a study that conjugated linoleic acid (CLA) was shown to be effective at fat loss, even without changing the activity level. I'm too lazy to cite that study because it was very small and only a couple of ladies benefited from CLA without needing to up their activity. The study overall didn't seem conclusive, to me, that CLA was actually all that effective. I bought CLA and took it for some time, but did *not* see any benefit despite increasing my activity significantly. So, as I stated in the beginning, there's not a magic pill that will make you lose weight.

Comment: On the subject of CLA... https://www.instagram.com/p/BzAWrqEB0uv/

Comment: Yup, CLA is a waste of money. Like, consuming fat is okay and all, but might as well consume fat that's in meat instead of paying a premium for sunflower seed oil (which I didn't know was CLA until a recent doctor's visit).

Comment: Actually, I just thought of an old weight loss pill that actually worked but was pretty lethal. I won't mention its name since it's a dangerous drug. `Dietary support` made me think of supplement which didn't get my brain to think of what I learned in biochemistry.